# How can I rotate a square shaped object using Mouse pointer in sfml?

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

I am new to using SFML and I was wondering if someone can tell me how to rotate an object at its center using a mouse pointer.

For example, if I press the `right` button it should rotate in clock-wise direction and if I press the `left` button it should rotate in anti-clockwise direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? If you need a further explanation, write it down.

```cpp
sf::RectangleShape shape;
shape.setSize({100.0f, 100.0f});

// Set origin point in the center of the object, to rotate it around the center
shape.setOrigin({shape.getSize().x / 2, shape.getSize().y / 2});

// Angle value you'll rotate the shape by
float angle = 1.0f;

// Inside the game loop
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Right)) shape.rotate(angle);
if (sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Button::Left))  shape.rotate(-angle);
```

Comment: I did the same thing...sorry, I should've written the code in the question.  But what happens is that it only picks up one command either the right button or the left one.

Comment: Isn't that how it should work? You cannot rotate a thing in two directions simultaneously.

Comment: I checked my code again and there were some silly mistakes I was making. It is working fine now. thank you.